# Dotcloud uWSGI Error

Tags: dotcloud

I am trying to deploy one of my applications on dotcloud. However, I keep getting:

```
uWSGI Error

wsgi application not found
```

Somebody could hint at some useful docs where this issue is discussed? My application is here:

```
https://github.com/kfk/datacrowd
```

and I do think everything is done by the tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you looked at this page or not, but it is a good resource for deploying flask apps onto dotCloud. http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/48/

Looking at your application, it looks like most things are setup correctly the only thing that looks a little odd is your `wsgi.py` file.

Have you tried to change your `wsgi.py` file so that it looks like this.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/dotcloud/current')
from datacrowd.app import app as application

application.config.update(DEBUG=True)
```

basically I removed the `if` statement at the end. Try that and see if it helps at all.

If not, try commenting out the `application.config.update(DEBUG=True)` line and see if that helps as well.

oh yeah one more thing, it looks like you have a `static` file instead of a `static` directory, not sure if you did that on purpose or not, but usually static is a directory where you put your static media, so that is most likely suppose to be symlink to `datacrowd/static`

**Update:**

Since you had the same error, then it is most likely something wrong with your application.

ssh into your service.

```
$ dotcloud ssh <app.service>
```

And then look at your logs in `/var/log/supervisor/uwsgi.log`, you will most likely see a syntax error, and a stack trace, telling you where the error is.

Common issues are usually

- dependencies not being installed
- Using features from a new version of python. (python 2.7, 3.x, features) when the python version on dotCloud is only 2.6.x.
- syntax typos (indent issues, etc)

Comment: Cleaned up the file as you advised, still giving me the error.

Comment: @kfk I updated my answer to include a few other things to look at.